# App is crashing only on samsung devices

Tags: android

I basically have a splash screen with the follywing code...I noticed that when I run it in most android devices,it works but only in samsung devices(not dependent on screen size,I tested on 4 devices) it caused a crash with this error...

LogCat-
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2c06feb8643dc1381db39b64e0834942

Crash--

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{inc.bs.ksit/inc.bs.ksit.Splash}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
```

Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/images"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="Powered by BS "
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView14" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

it worked on all other devices,any ideas?

Splash Activity

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 400;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Log.d("tag","splash");
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
 }
```

Comment: put your code and also complete log please

Comment: will do so in a few minutes...some formatting problem was coming when i was trying it so i was not able to upload

Comment: Is the image size too big ? Have you tried same app on Samsung latest mobiles (with improved hardware)

Comment: I tried it on my Samsung core 2 duos(4.7 inch) and Galaxy C7 pro(5.7 inch) but same result...it works on ALL OTHER Devices,that's why its weird,i can use a try,catch statement but i would like to know why only on samsung it crashes

Comment: What is the size of the image ?

Comment: 254x288 pixels 18 KB

Comment: I am pretty sure the crash is due to the resolution of the image used. It would be great if u could specify the resolution and size of the image or post an image here.

Comment: Try to use a different Image

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:
your referencing to `ImageView` before you create it, so I've just rearrange UI items, and if you have declared an id for a view, for ex `android:id="@+id/imageView"` you should remove `+` item on next refrence, so use `android:layout_below="@id/imageView"` isntade if `android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"`

Check this out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/images" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView13"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Powered by BS " />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nope,still crashing

Comment: @Swarnveer here is the explanation

Comment: Still crashing.

Comment: @HamidReza That is not the reason. It will not crash due to this. I myself tried the same and app is working fine without doing what you mentioned.

Comment: @Swarnveer I've tested this one on Samsung device and it's ok

Comment: @ShravanBhat there is some thing wrong with your resources, remove the image

Answer (score 0):

The crash can only be due to the image that you are currently using. There must be some odd dimensions. To solve this you can either use a different image or you can use a image caching library [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

A sample code for using Glide is

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int height = display.getHeight();
int width = display.getWidth();
final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.searchCityGuide);
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.exploref).asBitmap().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>((int) width, (int) height) {
@Override
public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(resource);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            layout.setBackground(drawable);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: where exploref is the image's name