# Android app crashing, but only on Samsung Galaxy

Tags: android, crash, samsung-mobile, error-reporting, samsung-galaxy

Several of my users are experiencing crashes, all with the same error (shown below). Strangely, they are all using variants of the Samsung Galaxy.

I read that it may be related to an Out-Of-Memory situation, but moved images to drawable-nodpi and enabled largeHeap. The error actually seems more frequent after this change!

My app has over 30 activities and 10 layouts, so I won`t share code.

If anyone could give me a clue about where to start looking, I would appreciate it. It would also be useful to hear some theories about why only Galaxies are doing this.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6261)
  at android.widget.TextView.performClick (TextView.java:11157)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:23748)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
```

Comment: May want to use additional crash reporting if you aren't already. Also if can't duplicate on a similar Samsung device (at least OS version), I would try a device test farm.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963198/app-is-crashing-only-on-samsung-devices

Answer (score 0):

Install Genymotion and clone Samsung Device on which your app is crashing and check logs..
I hope it helps